# Ubuntu Server - Allowing user to upload and download across the entire filesystem - sFTP

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, sftp, mobaxterm

I'm a Linux newbie.  I'm playing around with Ubuntu Server 22

I've got a standard image spun up using AWS.  I'm using MobaXTerm as my SSH client it has the facility to upload and create folders/files in the panel built into the application I believe through SFTP.

I'm logging into the server with SSH with a secure key file as the ubuntu user.  I'm only able to add/edit/delete files with this panel in the directory `/home/ubuntu/`

It's only me using this server and I'm wanting to add/edit and remove files quickly without using vim and other tools, it would be great to be able to use this facility across the entire filesystem but I'm getting the error permissions denied outside of the `/home/ubuntu/` directory.  How might I resolve this to allow the user `ubuntu' to add/remove files anywhere on the filesystem using this inbuilt facility in MobaXTerm which I think is using sFTP.  I accept this is not the safest practice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying some things.  Correct me if there is a better way to do this.  But I think ACL (access control lists) could be used here.

I downloaded the ACL package

`sudo apt-get install acl`

The for example I gave the ubuntu user full access to the etc directory.

`sudo setfacl -R -m u:ubuntu:rwx /etc`

UPDATE: Careful anyone doing this I'm just experimenting here as @damir pointed out in the comment here this did have serious results and locked the SSH access out of the server.  I'm doing this for learning and testing.

Again I'm not advocating logging in as the ROOT user account, but one way of allowing access to all files across the ubuntu server file system was simply to login as the ROOT user.

Comment: You should be very careful with this because there are "sensitive" files in /etc directory/ies. Test it first on an unimportant server. I'm currious how this worked at your server, because this should produce serious issues with ssh for example (and all other "sensitive" files).

Comment: @Damir  Thanks for your comment.  Yes, your absolutely right it did produce serious issues. And right again! SSH was broken after issuing this command.  I'm not sure why this was was ACL was just giving the Ubuntu user access but maybe there as a security policy in Ubuntu to check on this and broke things.

Comment: Yes. You can't do that!

Comment: @Hevski, if just SSH broken you can fix it with `sudo setfacl -R -x u:ubuntu /etc/ssh`. It should fix your ssh and you will be able to start your ssh or sshd deamon again... SSH host private keys (in /etc/ssh) are "sensitive" and giving more permission to them (than it is allowed) will produce your ssh/d deamon not being able to start (or accept new connections). I think your current ssh session will work until first disconnect (reconnect will not work I think), and ssh deamon will work until first stop (after first stop you won't be able to start it again). With command above ssh should work.

Comment: @Damir haha.  Yeah you're definitely right again.  I only found out that SSH was broken when I terminated the SSH connection and attempted to reconnect, ACCESS DENIED.  I was just spinning up multiple ubuntu server instances on AWS all for testing like this.  Makes sense that a permissions change on the /etc/ssh directory might trigger the iron security gates to drop.  I couldn't get back into the box after this.  But it is good learning.  Learn by mistake/breaking something and hopefully not break production! haha.